Допустимо ли для интеграционных тестов писать отдельные методы в репозиториях, которые нигде больше не используются в приложении кроме тестов?
Например в интеграционном тесте осуществляются действия с ентитями. По окончании теста я хочу проверить, что в БД у меня хранится определенное количество этих энтитей. Для этого в репозитории SomeEnityRepository extend JpaRepository я напишу метод count(), который возвращает мне количество записей в таблице. Этот метод count() в приложении больше нигде не используется. Допустимо ли писать такие методы, или такие запросы в тестах надо реализовать через entityManager/jdbcTemplate?

а кто вам может это запретить?

Мне сделали замечание, что так делать плохо. Но причину, почему это плохо, пока не объяснили.
